# Bundling an open source software with existing software

Tags: github, open-source, jfreechart

I have developed a java based Performance testing tool for thread pools and I am using JFreeChart library for drawing graphs in my tool. Now I want to distribute my software as an open source on gitHub. I read in End-User-License agreement on github that "you may not repackage or bundle the Software with any other software" . Now my question is that "does this means that I cant distribute my tool which is using JFreeChart Library". If this is the case then how can I make use of JFreeChart in my tool?

Comment: Do you mean this [*End-User License Agreement*](https://mac.github.com/eula.html) "regarding your use of GitHub's desktop applications."

Answer (score 0):

Github's terms of use have no say over the software you can develop, modify, or publish. At most, they can dictate what you host on their site. In practice, Github does not restrict how you bundle projects hosted on their site.

According to its website, [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is released under the [LGPL](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html), and *that* is the license you need to concern yourself with, since it is JFreeChart, not Github, that you are trying to bundle.

While you should review the LGPL yourself in order to decide if what you want to do is permitted, in general the LGPL "[*allows developers and companies to use and integrate software released under the LGPL into their own (even proprietary) software*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License)".

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to use some dependency management tool like maven. This way you declare your dependency, in this case like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
    <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.14</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you doesn't have to upload JFreeChart into your repo, but everyone who wants to download your tool from Github can easily run 'mvn install' or something like that and JFreeChart is automatically downloaded.

Comment: If you have a dependency on an external project, you must respect that project's license, whether you package the library yourself or simply tell users to install the external project alongside yours. When you depend on a third party library your project is a "[derived work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work)". Some licenses, notably the [GPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License), directly restrict what you can and cannot do with your project if it's dependent on GPL-licensed code.